# What type of visa required for Sweden onsite interview?

Tags: sweden, pakistan

After initial interviews I got an offer for an onsite interview in Sweden (the company will bear all expenses).

I want to stay there for 1-2 days and I need to know what visa category suites my situation. I am a citizen from Pakistan.
Some people have guided me to apply for a business visa, but I can't present all required documents, i.e. a recommendation letter from the Chamber of Commerce.

I have tried to call the Swedish embassy, but no one picked up the phone.

Comment: Has the company not given an indication of what visa you require? Normally HR departments are pretty-well on top of stuff like this...

Comment: @MarkMayo: not if it's a small company that doesn't have a lot of experience hiring visa-requiring people.

Comment: @MarkMayo You are right, the company was a startup and it was first time they were going to offer someone from other country to come and appear in interview...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT, removed old answer**

In response to DJClayworth, yes business visas are different from work visas. Work visas allow you to work in the country as part of a business or on your own. Business visas are required if you're travelling to visit a business in the country for work.

However, my old answer was wrong. Since Sweden has a separate business visas that would be required for business visits, training, and conferences. Not all European countries draw this distinction (the base visa is still a Schengen C-visa).

Since the company is paying the expenses, and you'll need to explain this on the visa, I think you do need a business visa. Otherwise you stand a chance of being refused when you explain how you're paying for your stay.

However, definitely check with the inviting company, they should know or at least be able to find out more easily. And e-mail the Embassy, I've had great results e-mailing embassies -- I almost never call because they rarely answer their phones.

Comment: Business visas are different from work visas. If you are going to a business meeting, conference etc. then you usually need a business visa. Many countries hand out business visas pretty freely, usually as freely as tourist visas. but that doesn't make them the same thing. This page for example has separate visas for business and work. http://www.swedenabroad.com/en-GB/Embassies/Istanbul/Visit-Sweden/Visa-for-visiting-Sweden/Business-Visa/

Comment: You're correct, Sweden has a separate business visa class. I've edited my answer to indicate this. Thanks.

Comment: Probably best to remove the wrong bit of your answer and just leave the right bit.

Comment: You're right, I've removed the old answer and left the stuff after the edit.

Comment: @SpaceDog Thanks for help, yes business visa required for onsite interview in sweden, they dont have specific category for such purpose.